# mock class with internal constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, internal, nsubstitute

I have some class that I want to mock and that has only an internal expecting some arguments. Therefor I added the `InternalsVisibleTo`-attribute to my system under test and wrote the following code:

```
var target = Substitute.For<MyClass>(testArgs);
```

where `MyClass` is this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass(int i) { ... }
}
```

When debugging I get a `NotSupporetedException` because I don´t have a default-constructor. However as I have an internal one (which is visible to my test-assembly because of `InternalsVisibleTo`) I´d expect that one to be used instead.

Of course I could just make the constructor public but this would allow any user of my API to create instances of `MyClass` which I´d like to avoid. Is there anything I missed to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don´t have to expose the class´ constructor to the API, all we have to do is make the constructor `internal protected` to make it visible to classes deriving from `MyClass` *or* classes within the assembly where `MyClass` is located. Thus NSubstitute is able to create a class that derives from `MyClass` and redirects the constructor-call to the base-constructor.